# How to import pip installed packages in Pybind11?

Tags: python, pybind11

Iam trying making python embedding code in c++ side.

I succeed to make simple example by using Pybind11.

calc.py :

```
def say():
  return "Hello world!"
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/embed.h> // everything needed for embedding

namespace py = pybind11;


int main()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive
    
    try
    {
        py::module_ calc = py::module_::import("calc");
        py::object result = calc.attr("say")();
        py::print(result);
    }
    catch (py::error_already_set & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

output:

```
Hello world!
```

Everything is okay now.

But I don't know how to use the pre-installed packages.

If i put numpy code at top of calc.py, i could see exception.

```
import numpy # <-- it makes error

def say():
  return "Hello world!"
```

> ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.10 from
>   "D:\Workspace\Playgrounds\PyExample\x64\Debug\PyExample.exe"   * The
>   NumPy version is: "1.23.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

If i run as like below. the script works without any problem.

```
python calc.py
```

I tried download numpy to specific folder and added that folder to sys.path. The resulting is the same.

Built-in modules(sys, os..) is working well.

I am also confusing whether it is possible to import site-packages in embedded python code or not.

Can you give me peice of advices?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "How to import pip installed packages in Pybind11?" the answer is to import it, the same way you imported calc.py in your sample code:

```
 py::module np = py::module::import("numpy");
```

Because `python calc.py` doesn't actually need the numpy library in the call to `say()`, the problem with your numpy installation is not revealed -- the library is "lazy-loaded" in this case.
If you add a line within the `say()` function which references numpy, you'll find that error occurs in python too.

Why the numpy import error occurs is, literally, a different question altogether!

Comment: Thanks for comment. My command line environment is working well. Even i put some numpy's code in say function. I just want to know how to use none builtin packages in embedded python code.

Comment: A bit confused by this: does the C++ Numpy import exist throughout the scope of the program here? Say we wanted to optimize for performance when actually executing the Python script itself; does "pre-importing" the packages, like Numpy, via `py::module::import("numpy")` help with this?